# Camera calibration using a rendered calibration board

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, aruco

I'm trying to calibrate a camera with obvious radial lens distortion that's focused on a big screen which fills most of the image.

As I'm a lazy bum, I don't want to wave a calibration board around in front of the camera, and instead created this video here with the ARUCO calibration board rendered in various poses: https://youtu.be/D73H6IJdbkg

While this plays on the big screen, I just have the camera take a picture every two seconds, take the pile of images, and can then calculate the calibration parameters with the usual OpenCV methods (specifically, with `calibrateCameraAruco`).

However, the calibration result kinda sucks.

The intrinsic parameters (focal length, optical center) are pretty much accurate as far as I can tell (optical center is close to half the image resolution, focal length is somewhere around 300 pixels which seems about right for a wide-angle lens), but the radial distortion parameters that I get don't really seem to have any effect (as in, if I apply them to undistort the camera picture, it looks nearly identical as before, with more or less the same radial distortion).

What am I missing here?

**Update:**

As @ChristophRackwitz correctly pointed out, this entire idea is based on a wrong assumption. When I render the calibration board in various sizes and poses, I'm implicitly creating a second virtual camera with its own unknown set of parameters, and trying to do a camera calibration with the resulting images will just give me a random (?) mashup between the two parameter sets, so no shortcuts and back to the physical calibration board.

Comment: there is absolutely no point in displaying perspectives of an aruco. none of those give you any information on the lens. your focal length, to a significant part, is determined by your virtual camera that you used to produce perspective views of the marker. I think you'll have to abandon the "lazy" strategy. what you're missing is the entire theory and math behind computer vision.

Comment: Ah sheesh, you're right about the virtual camera.  There's some residues left in my brain from reading Hartley & Zisserman ~ 10 years ago, but I guess I'll have to dig that book up again now. 